# Tikz : change size of arrow head for angle 60

Tags: tikz-arrows

I need to use the arrow call `angle 60` but i want the arrow head to be bigger.

I tried the code below but the `scale` (or `length` or `width`) parameter doesn't work for `angle 60` (but it works on `Triangle`) and i can't find anything on google...

[image: arrows]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,rectangle] (A) {\textbf{A}};
\node[draw,rectangle,right=2.5 of A] (B) {\textbf{B}};
\draw[-{angle 60}] (A) -- (B);

\node[draw,rectangle,below=1 of A] (C) {\textbf{C}};
\node[draw,rectangle] (D) at(B|-C) {\textbf{D}};
\draw[-{angle 60[scale=3]}] (C) -- (D);

\node[draw,rectangle,below=1 of C] (E) {\textbf{E}};
\node[draw,rectangle] (F) at(D|-E) {\textbf{F}};
\draw[-{Triangle}] (E) -- (F);

\node[draw,rectangle,below=1 of E] (G) {\textbf{G}};
\node[draw,rectangle] (H) at(F|-G) {\textbf{H}};
\draw[-{Triangle[scale=3]}] (G) -- (H);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any tip ?

Comment: In general, arrow heads whose name starts with a capital letter (e.g. `Triangle`) are from the newer `arrows.meta` library. These arrow heads can take options in brackets, such as `scale`, see the description of `arrows.meta` in the manual. On other hand, arrow heads whose name starts with a lower case letter (like `angle 60`) is a default one, or from the older `arrows` library. These do not take options, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the arrow `Straight Barb` from `arrows.meta` and set `angle'=60`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,rectangle] (A) {\textbf{A}};
\node[draw,rectangle,right=2.5 of A] (B) {\textbf{B}};
\draw[-{angle 60}] (A) -- (B);

\node[draw,rectangle,below=1 of A] (C) {\textbf{C}};
\node[draw,rectangle] (D) at(B|-C) {\textbf{D}};
\draw[-{Straight Barb[angle'=60,scale=4]}] (C) -- (D);

\node[draw,rectangle,below=1 of C] (E) {\textbf{E}};
\node[draw,rectangle] (F) at(D|-E) {\textbf{F}};
\draw[-{Triangle}] (E) -- (F);

\node[draw,rectangle,below=1 of E] (G) {\textbf{G}};
\node[draw,rectangle] (H) at(F|-G) {\textbf{H}};
\draw[-{Triangle[scale=4]}] (G) -- (H);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to define `{Straight Barb[angle'=60,scale=4]}` in `pgfplotset`?